# Brown sugar + Bread =?

Tags: bread, sugar, food-preservation, brown-sugar

So I always put bread in my brown sugar just because that what my mom always did, but I never understood why? I think it's supposed to make the brown sugar not clump. How does it work?

Comment: We'd use half an apple, but only after the brown sugar had hardened. (not all the time) Same idea. With a tightly sealed container, not often needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The moisture from the bread is absorbed by the brown sugar. After a while, the bread will be like a withered old mummified piece of white toast. Get rid of it, and put a new piece of bread in there.

Comment: ... which keeps the brown sugar from turning into a bunch of rocks that you have to crush up, but has no moisture, so behaves more like granulated sugar when you try to use it.